# all possible abbreviations of a string in order

Tags: string, permutation

I came across this question from my friend. Given a string of characters, generate all possible abbreviations of those characters such that these abbreviations have the characters sequenced in the same order as the original.

For eg. for "abc", valid abbreviations would be a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc

I have been trying to come up with a simple solution to this problem, so far no luck. Any lead would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Tell your friend that this isn't a "question". If you'd like it to be answered, please edit your post to make it into one. Also, please include some information about which **programming language** you'd like to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone come up with a solution, it could be done with a binary mask, one digit per character. So for "abc", there are 2 x 2 x 2 possibilities. 000 - 111. Incrementing a variable from 000 to 111, then removing a character where there's a zero, leaves a list of the valid options.

Comment: Any programming language is welcome. Does this problem have a recursive solution? @jodes: that is indeed a smart answer! Thanks